# Changing input language does not work while entering keyring password

Tags: password, input-language, keyrings

On startup, a keyring message pops up. Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> → <kbd>Space</kbd> does not change the language, instead of that, it adds spaces in the password text field.

If the language used in the password is different from the language that was set by the computer on startup then it is impossible to enter the password.

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, gnome

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. I cannot confirm this behavior under KUbuntu. please edit your question to provide the OS, version and Desktop environment you are using.

Comment: It is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, gnome